# Help - Light switches

Tags: electrical

My basement is long and mostly finished- There are three light switches at both ends,  I built a bedroom in the centre of the room, so I moved the lights and tried to put a new light switch for four of the light, now I can not get any of then to work. The wire has a red, black and white, but the switch only has two screws. Please help

---

One of the boxes this is the one  that works

[image]

---

light switches more photos to come

[image]

---

More of the basement lights and switches

[image]

---

More of the basement lights and switches

[image]

---

More of the basement lights and switches

[image]

Comment: It would help a lot to see some photos of the inside of the box.  Have you tried attaching the switch to the red and black?

Comment: Hi Samanta, welcome to the Home Improvement part of Stack Exchange. Your question will need a lot more details about how things were wired and how you changed it before it stopped working. The folks here are not able to enter your basement to take a look so we need your help.

Comment: There were three sets of pot lights- each set had a light switch on both ends of the room. I could only get one set to work. In the new room I have the four pot lights connected. The wire in the switch box has a red, black, white and ground, the new switch only has two screws both the same colour- I then used a wire with black and white with aground and attached the three lights

Comment: Hi Samantha. Instructions for uploading photos are here: https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer

Comment: Use the [edit] link underneath your question to update it with new information.

Comment: You've now got a lot of pictures, but you need to spend more time actually giving us info we can use to help you. For instance, a wiring diagram would really help.

Answer (score 1):

To wire your lamp to be controlled by 3 or more switches the "middle" switches must be "intermediate" or "cross-over" switches with 4 terminals, which cross the strapping/traveller pair.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#More_than_two_locations